# git слить ветку в master, но без одного коммита посередине

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть ветка master с коммитом A.
От нее была создана ветка dev, на ней коммиты B, C, D.

Мне нужно слить в master все изменения A-B (т.е. простой fast-forward до B)
И потом слить все изменения C-D.
Одним словом, изменения сделанные B-C в ветку master попасть не должны.

Какое может быть решение?

Comment: Какие-то костыли по-моему. А уверен, что те изменения никак не влияют на логику работы программы и что ничего не поломаются? Что в тех изменениях, что ты решил так сделать?

Comment: фича, которую не приняли

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389977/4827341

Comment: А делали бы по бранчу на фичу локально у себя, было бы много проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

насколько я понял изложенное, у вас есть история коммитов вида:

```
a → b → c → d
```

и вы хотите один из коммитов (`c`) полностью убрать из истории.

сделать это можно, например, командой `rebase`:

```
$ git rebase --onto хэш-этого-коммита^ хэш-этого-коммита
```

если удаляемый коммит затрагивает те же файлы (а в них те же строки), что и последующий коммит(ы), то команда `rebase` завершится неудачей. поэтому лучше сначала потренироваться на временной ветке, создав её из текущей:

```
$ git checkout -b testbranch
```

---

пример:

```
$ git log --oneline 
82c7fb4 d
6c9d6d6 c
f1f9d9c b
03b0751 a
```

удаляем коммит `c` (хэш — `6c9d6d6`):

```
$ git rebase --onto 6c9d6d6^ 6c9d6d6
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: d
$ git log --oneline 
cf783ab d
f1f9d9c b
03b0751 a
```

как видим, у коммита `d` поменялся хэш. если бы после него были ещё коммиты, у них бы тоже поменялись хэши. собственно, так и должно было произойти: мы ведь поменяли историю для всех коммитов, являющихся потомками удаляемого коммита.